# Raspberry Pi as standalone Server for Octoprint

Tags: raspberry-pi, octoprint

I am working on Octoprint for 3Dprinter. Using Raspberry Pi as server and it is working fine with Raspbian OS.
But the system works only when it is connected to internet. Can I run the same without internet and How I can change the UI.

Comment: This is not a programming question, please find another Stackexchange site to query.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't have to be connected to the internet, but OctoPrint is a web server so in order to connect to it, you need to at least have a LAN connection between your client and your Raspberry Pi.  If you just intend to use it from localhost (ie client and server are the same machine) you just need enough networking to allow loopback to work.  Which as idstam pointed out isn't a programming question.

On changing the UI, that could be a programming question, but your query is very non-specific. OctoPrint is written in python and has a pretty rich plugin system to allow you to add UI and replace parts of the UI. It is also well documented at http://docs.octoprint.org.